# Cannot open log for source 'blah'. You may not have write access. Eh?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-log

I'm, attempting to write to a custom event log .... but I get the error:

Win32Exception Access Is Denied
Cannot open log for source 'blah'. You may not have write access.

I've trawled the net.. followed varions links and to date the best one I've come across is 
[this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028427). It's not as clear as it could be though....

This is a 2008 R2 development server.
I've added the following REG_SZ key "CustomSD" with a value of 
O:BAG:SYD:(A;; 0x7;;;AN)(A;; 0x7;;;SY)(A;; 0x7;;;BA)(A;; 0x7;;;SO)(A;; 0x7;;;IU)(A;; 0x7;;;SU)

to registry folders "eventlog" and my sub folders.

I've also allowed everyone full access to the physical event log (.evtx file)... but all to no avail...

I think I'm giving Read Write and Clear access to the various account types (SY=System etc,).

My website which fails is running under the default IISAPPPool account.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Comment: What's the full path of your added registry value?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET runs in a reduced trust environment.

If your event log source does not already exist, then registry keys will have to be added in order to create it.

But that won't work in the reduced-trust environment.

You should create an installer class for the event source you're using, then "install" the web site during deployment. The fastest way to do this is to create a "Component" to do your event logging, drag an Event Log component onto the design surface, set the properties, then choose the command to create an installer.

At deployment time, you'll just have to run "installutil" against your web application's DLL. The event source will be created before your web application starts.

Comment: The log already exists, plus if I browse to the website (my account is a member of administrators) then I can write to the log. It's only a 'normal' user that cannot write to the log.

Comment: I should have said we're using windows authentication.

Comment: @Jim: if you are using the Windows Event Log, then existence is not the problem. Creating an event log source requires the creation of registry keys. This is what is not being permitted.

Comment: @John Saunders... thanks for your reply.. the event source is already there too... as I say... browse to the website as an administrator and events get logged

Comment: @Jim: after browsing as admin, and after events get logged, are you then able to get them logged as a non-admin?

Comment: @John - No, a non-admin cannot log events.

Comment: @Jim: please post the complete exception you receive. Catch the exception, then post ex.ToString().